# how to show else condition messages in sweetalert error popup using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm scratching my head for a couple of days now and I can't get SweetAlert2 popup in my else condition as a error using ajax. i m tring to get a error if my if condition does not true.

Here is my JS code where i set sweetalert2 popup code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#card-form-elem").submit(function (event) {
        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        $(".help-block").remove();

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "cardform.php",
                data: $("#card-form-elem").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                encode: true,
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (!data.success) {
                    if (data.errors.cardnumber) {
                        $("#cardnumber-group").addClass("has-error");
                        $("#cardnumber-group").focus();
                        $("#cardnumber-group").append(
                            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.cardnumber + "</div>"
                        );
                    }

                    if (data.errors.expiry) {
                        $("#expiry-group").addClass("has-error");
                        $("#expiry-group").focus();
                        $("#expiry-group").append(
                            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.expiry + "</div>"
                        );
                    }

                    if (data.errors.cardholder) {
                        $("#cardholder-group").addClass("has-error");
                        $("#cardholder-group").focus();
                        $("#cardholder-group").append(
                            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.cardholder + "</div>"
                        );
                    }

                    if (data.errors.cardcvv) {
                        $("#cardcvv-group").addClass("has-error");
                        $("#cardcvv-group").focus();
                        $("#cardcvv-group").append(
                            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.cardcvv + "</div>"
                        );
                    }

                    if (data.errors.cardaddress) {
                        $("#cardaddress-group").addClass("has-error");
                        $("#cardaddress-group").focus();
                        $("#cardaddress-group").append(
                            '<div class="help-block">' +
                            data.errors.cardaddress +
                            "</div>"
                        );
                    }

                    if (data.errors.payingOf) {
                        $("#paying-group").addClass("has-error");
                        $("#paying-group").focus();
                        $("#paying-group").append(
                            '<div class="help-block">' +
                            data.errors.payingOf +
                            "</div>"
                        );
                    }


                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'Required Filled Are Not Filled!'
                    })
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Good job!',
                        text: data.message,
                    })

                    $("form").trigger("reset");
                    setInterval(function () {
                        $(location).attr("href", "index.php");
                    }, 4000);
                }
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: data.error,
                    footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
                })
            });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

now i going to share my PHP code where i used if condition and sql query

```
include("staff_session.php");
$errors = [];
$data = [];

$cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];
$cardholder = $_POST['cardholder'];
$expiry = $_POST['expiry'];   
$cardcvv = $_POST['cardcvv'];
$cardaddress= $_POST['cardaddress'];   
$payingOf= $_POST['payingOf']; 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$bookingid = $_POST['booking_id'];

$flag = true;

if (empty($_POST['cardnumber'])) {
    $errors['cardnumber'] = 'Card Number is required.';
    $flag = false;
}


if (empty($_POST['cardholder'])) {
    $errors['cardholder'] = 'Card Holder Name is required.';
    $flag = false;
}

if (empty($_POST['expiry'])) {
    $errors['expiry'] = 'Expiry is required.';
    $flag = false;
}

if (empty($_POST['cardcvv'])) {
    $errors['cardcvv'] = 'Card CVV is required.';
    $flag = false;
}
if (empty($_POST['cardaddress'])) {
    $errors['cardaddress'] = 'Card Address is required.';
    $flag = false;
}
if ($_POST['payingOf'] == "--Select Option--") {
    $errors['payingOf'] = 'Select Paying By.';
    $flag = false;
}



if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
} else {
          
          


                $url = "update-profile.php?username=".$username;
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `agent_details` WHERE username='$username'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($rows == 1){

                if($flag){    
                    
                    $cardquery = "SELECT * FROM `creditcard` WHERE card_number='$cardnumber'";
                    $cardresult = mysqli_query($conn, $cardquery);
                    $cardrows = mysqli_num_rows($cardresult);
                    $findRow = mysqli_fetch_array($cardresult);
                    if($cardrows == 0)
                    {
                        $carddetails = "INSERT INTO `creditcard`(`holder_name`, `cvv_number`, `card_number`, `exp_date`,`bookingid`,`cardaddress`, `username`, `paying`) VALUES ('$cardholder','$cardcvv','$cardnumber','$expiry','$bookingid','$cardaddress','$username','$payingOf')";                
                        mysqli_query($conn,$carddetails);

                        $notes = $bookingid." Customer Card Added!";  
                        $noteficationStatus = "Card Added";
                        $status = 0;
                        $sql= "INSERT INTO `notifications`(`comment`, `bookingid`, `created_by`, `created_to`,`process`, `status`)VALUES('$notes','$bookingid','$username','$username','$noteficationStatus','$status')";

                                

                        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                        $data['success'] = true;
                        $data['message'] = $bookingid.' Has Been Successfully Added! ';
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {                        
                        $findBookingID = $findRow['bookingid'];                    
                        $data['success'] = false;
                        $data['error'] = 'This Card is Already Enter in Booking ID '.$findBookingID;
                    }

                    
                    
                }else{
                    $data['success'] = false;
                    $data['message'] = 'There is Some error';
                }
            }else{
                $data['success'] = false;
                $data['message'] = 'You Can,t Create Case! Complete your Profile!';
                header("Location:$url");
                }
        }

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Hi Amit, it would help us all if this sample code was down to a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is a lot to read through. I'd suggest seeing if you can replace your `Swal` with `alert()`. If that doesn't work, you know it is your jQuery structure. Also, I don't think `.fail()` takes `data`, so your problem might be the method params. [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)